# Unable to resolve JRE: jdk7 (Standard VM)

Tags: eclipse, spring, ant

I am currently creating a spring app. 
Previously, I had been able to do ANT builds in eclipse but now I am not able to. When I now try to do ANT build, it says [JRE]: Unable to resolve JRE: jdk7 (Standard VM).

It will not allow me to run the ANT build. I restarted eclipse as well as my computer but nothing works.

I tried seeing if changing between the jre7 and jdk1.7 in the installed jre's but that did not do anything.

I think it has to with me uninstalling all the Java updates I had on my computer and installing the new jdk. It started happening after I did that.

Comment: Did you update the Installed JREs entry to point to the newly installed JDK/JRE?

Comment: Yes. I was able to solve it. Apparently, I had to do go to the JRE tab and set the execution environment. I had set it everywhere else and assumed it was set but apparently not.

Answer (score 1):

Try going to Eclipse's Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Compiler

Check out the Java version you're using.

Then go to Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs

There choose the JRE that fits your Java version. (for example Java 1.7 fits JRE 7).

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure that your javac.exe is in the path. Oracle did an install of a new JRE and put C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath at the front of my path. I got this error even though I had not changed the JRE under the JDK I was using.

After checking the Installed JRE and then verifying my path pointed first to the JDK bin folder, I then checked the JRE tab of the ant file launch config. The tab had an error indicator icon. I had specified "Separate JRE" in the "Runtime JRE" section. I clicked "Run in the same JRE as the workspace", then back on "Separate JRE", then selected the same JRE by browsing "Installed JREs..." and the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

The possible reason for this error is that no JRE is configured for ant configuration. Select build.xml and go to run->External tool confoguration of ant. In the configuration window navigate to jre tab and select the appropriate jre from the available option.